# Production and Test Server using Git

Tags: git, development-environment, production-environment

I am running a PHP - MySQL website, and have set up a remote repository on my own server using Git.

I now want a way to be able to have a production and a test server, and some how be able to push my changes from dev to production easily. and seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use git for deployment.

Setup, like, usual build proccess. Build a zip, do minification and lint and friends along the way...and have configuration in separate file.

And use BuildBot or Hudson or whatever to automate it.

Future generations will thank You.

Comment: Why do you advise so strongly against git? How do I best use BuildBot or Hudson then?

Comment: Not against git, but against using any VCS as deployment tools. For Hudson/BuildBot, see their documentations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a deployment system with git by setting up a `post-update` hook on the production server's repository.

If you don't need a deployment system, but only want some of the files in the repo deployed, you can use a `.gitattributes` file and the `git-archive` command in the `post-update` hook.

Answer (score 0):

If Git is the route you want to go, try having two separate branches of the code (`test` and `production`).  Do all your work on `test`, make sure it functions properly, then merge it into `production`.  Set your server to read files from the `production` branch and you should be in business.

I agree with @Almad, though - if you're looking for a more robust deployment solution, a VCS is not the way to go (since deployment kind of cuts against the VCS' purpose).